# Get FMU/FMI from Anylogic Model

Tags: anylogic, fmi

I looking into developing a DES model in Anylogic and wanted to know if there is an out of the box solution to getting the FMU from the tool, so the model can be migrated to another platform at a later stage if needed.

I do not have extensive knowledge with Anylogic apart from working a bit with it during studies.

If it is not possible, is it something you recommend writing manually on the side, if even possible?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Apart from searching in the official documentation, I have not tried a lot yet. Many sites recommend using FMI but it seems like quite the work to manually write whilst developing the DES model.

Comment: You may want to clarify what FMU and FMI means. But afaik there is no such build-in support. But AnyLogic is pure Java so either find a Java library that does what you need or you code what you need :)

Comment: @benjamin : for information on the Functional Mock-up Interface (FMI) and a Functional Mock-up Unit (FMU) see https://fmi-standard.org/ and the inctrocutory slides from the FMI Beginners Tutorial https://github.com/modelica/fmi-beginners-tutorial-2023/tree/main/part1

Comment: then my answer stands: no build-in support. Either find a Java package that helps or code what you need :)